# Embedded Persistence solution in Apache Camel to save dead letter message

Tags: apache-camel

Is there any embedded persistence solution shipped with Camel API? I want to save my dead letter messages. It can be done through DB or JMS queue but I want to avoid it while shipping to clients.
I read about HawtDB in 'Camel In Action'. But it seems to be tightly coupled with Aggregator EIP.
  Later i want to create a report on all the dead letter messages and show it to Client.

Comment: @HenrykKonsek You are so generous. I will surely send you my Fuse ESB related SO question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use any persistence component to save your dead letter messages ([Hibernate](http://camel.apache.org/hibernate.html), [JPA](http://camel.apache.org/jpa.html), [JDBC](http://camel.apache.org/jdbc.html), [DB4O](http://camel.apache.org/db4o.html), etc.). In case of majority of persistence components you will not save the message itself, but selected (meta)data from it (the notable exception from that is the case of using DB4O component).

For example if you're sending Hibernates entities in messages, you can use [Hibernate component](http://camel.apache.org/hibernate.html):

```
from("seda:deadMessageStore").
  setBody().groovy("new DeadMessageLog(request.headers, request.body) ").
  to("hibernate:com.foo.DeadMessageLog");
errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("seda:deadMessageStore"));
```

If you cannot predict what kind of classes will you send to the dead letter queue, consider using [DB4O component](http://camel.apache.org/db4o.html). DB4O is extremely flexible in that matter since it allows you to store any Java object in the your queue (without explicit mapping, like in the case of the Hibernate or JPA).

```
// store any Java object without transformations
errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("db4o:java.lang.Object"))
```

Also creating embedded DB40 container is very simple:

```
ObjectContainer db = Db4oEmbedded.openFile(Db4oEmbedded.newConfiguration(), DB4OFILENAME);
```

Comment: But they all will be external databases. Isn't it? I need to ask clients to create a separate table in there databases for dead letter messages. I am trying to avoid it and provide camel as simple pluggable solution.

Comment: DB4O allows you to store to the filesystem. The same with the Hibernate with SQLLite driver.

Comment: @HenryKonsek How about HawtDBAggregationRepository? It am reading about this option right now.

Comment: Aggregation repository is for persisting shared state of aggregation. As I understand for your question, you are interested in the dead letter queue not in storing an aggregation state. If you want to create an audit of your dead letter messages - use the solution I write you in the answer :) .